# How to Create custom permission classes?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

models:

```
class DoctorProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=50, blank=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(_('mobile'), unique=True, max_length=10, blank=False)
    # mobile=  models.CharField(primary_key=True , max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
    # mobile= models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(10),MaxValueValidator(10)])
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(_('password'),max_length=25,blank=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_verified=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False)
    is_doctor = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False)
    otp = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    dob=models.DateField()
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
  )
   gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

How to Create custom permission for creating tasks ?
eg:

```
class ClinicRegistrationView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = ClinicSerializer
     queryset = Doctor_clinic.objects.all()
     permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)#token user can create
```

How to give is_doctor permission ,only create task ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission


class IsDoctorPermission(BasePermission):
    """
    Check if user is a doctor.
    """

    message = "The user is not a doctor."

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.is_doctor
```

and add this permission to the view

```
class ClinicRegistrationView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = ClinicSerializer
     queryset = Doctor_clinic.objects.all()
     permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsDoctorPermission)
```

Comment: Working ,  this class (IsDoctorPermission) is suporting  all crud operations or not ?

Comment: @Prashanth Yes, you can apply it to all request methods.

Comment: login patient also get this token and perform the operation also

Comment: @Prashanth Can you describe the problem in detail?

Comment: i am defined two models one is doctor another one is patients module after login this two users get the on token and perform the operations , so problem is doctor adding(create)hospital details so after login persion also allowing to create eg(patient also get the token the token user creating this class ) this function is accepting every token person for creating but i need for creating only "is_doctor", is_doctor permissions is working after activating the doctor and also when i activating is_doctor , automatically patient token also accting this permissions....

Answer (score 0):

you can to this

```
class ClinicRegistrationView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     serializer_class = ClinicSerializer
     queryset = Doctor_clinic.objects.all()

     
     def get_permissions(self):
         if self.action == "create":
            permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny,]
         else:
            permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,]
         return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

Comment: not working, not showing any action method.